ruby function adding pkg exclusion if not already exists in each repo defined in repo file
I am trying to create ruby function (within chef cookbook) adding package exclusion string to each repo defined in /etc/yum.repos.d/repo.repo.
In example, for pkg zabbix* it search each repo and add 'exclude=zabbix*' if not already added, behind the last repo config line.
What i was try so far looks like this:
def self.exclude_pkg(repo_file, exclude)
  File.open(repo_file, 'r+') do |file|
    lines = file.readlines
    sections = lines.each_with_index.group_by { |line, _| line.strip.start_with?('[') }

    sections.each do |_found, section|
      next unless section.none? { |row, _index| row.strip == "exclude=#{exclude}" }
      puts 'section: ' + section.to_s
      insert_row = section.reverse_each.find { |row, _index| !row.empty? }
      section.insert(insert_row + 1, "exclude=#{exclude}\n")
    end

    file.seek(0)
    file.write(sections.flat_map { |_, section_rows| section_rows })
  end
end

in this example i want to find all epel repos and exclude all zabbix packages, so i call the function like this:
to_exclude = 'zabbix*'
files = Dir.glob('/etc/yum.repos.d/*epel*repo')
files.each do |repo_file|
  exclude_pkg(repo_file, to_exclude)
end

But so far i receive error:
TypeError
no implicit conversion of Integer into Array

in
 10:        sections.each do |_found, section|
 11:          next unless section.none? { |row, _index| row.strip == "exclude=#{exclude}" }
 12:          puts 'section: ' + section.to_s
 13:          insert_row = section.reverse_each.find { |row, _index| !row.empty? }
 14>>         section.insert(insert_row + 1, "exclude=#{exclude}\n")
 15:        end
 16:  
 17:        file.seek(0)
 18:        file.write(sections.flat_map { |_, section_rows| section_rows })
 19:      end
 20:    end
 21:  end

how such a function should be constructed so that:

was able to separate sections (each section represents a repo, currently I separate them by finding the square bracket sign [)
check whether an exception consistent with the pattern is already defined in the section
add an exception after the last non-blank line in a section if the exception is not already defined

Example input file (exclusion added only to the last section):
[ol9_baseos_latest]
name=Oracle Linux 9 BaseOS Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/baseos/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1

[ol9_appstream]
name=Oracle Linux 9 Application Stream Packages ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
exclude=zabbix*

Example output file:
[ol9_baseos_latest]
name=Oracle Linux 9 BaseOS Latest ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/baseos/latest/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
exclude=zabbix*

[ol9_appstream]
name=Oracle Linux 9 Application Stream Packages ($basearch)
baseurl=https://yum$ociregion.$ocidomain/repo/OracleLinux/OL9/appstream/$basearch/
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
exclude=zabbix*

Thank you very much for your invaluable help!

insert_row is an Array of [row,index] which you are then trying to add 1 to. If your whole goal is to just add this at the end of the "section" then section << "exclude=#{exclude}" would work. Also you can drop the index from everything since you never use it. There are definitely other improvements that could be made but the question would certainly benefit from example input and output as well.

There are some existing methods to edit lines in files as well. Chef file edit has some methods. There's also a line cookbook that might be worth considering.
